# Importing wrongly concatenated JSONs in python

Tags: python, json, regex

I've a text document that has several thousand jsons strings in the form of: `"{...}{...}{...}"`. This is not a valid json it self but each `{...}` is.

I currently use the following a regular expression to split them:

```
fp = open('my_file.txt', 'r')
raw_dataset = (re.sub('}{', '}\n{', fp.read())).split('\n')
```

Which basically breaks every line where a curly bracket closes and other opens (`}{ -> }\n{`) so I can split them into different lines.

The problem is that few of them have a `tags` attribute written as `"{tagName1}{tagName2}"` which breaks my regular expression.

An example would be:

```
'{"name":\"Bob Dylan\", "tags":"{Artist}{Singer}"}{"name": "Michael Jackson"}'
```

Is parsed into

```
'{"name":"Bob Dylan", "tags":"{Artist}'
'{Singer}"}'
'{"name": "Michael Jackson"}'
```

instead of

```
'{"name":"Bob Dylan", "tags":"{Artist}{Singer}"}'
'{"name": "Michael Jackson"}'
```

What is the proper way of achieve this for further json parsing?

Comment: `{ name : "foo" }` is also not json. `{ "name" : "foo" }` is json. Note the double quotes.

Comment: Is the format of data in each `{}` same ? I mean does each data start with `{name` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl you are right, I just fix them

Comment: @noob not necessarily.

Comment: @fuxes: Could you release some more data ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the raw_decode method of json.JSONDecoder

```
>>> import json
>>> d = json.JSONDecoder()
>>> x='{"name":\"Bob Dylan\", "tags":"{Artist}{Singer}"}{"name": "Michael Jackson"}'
>>> d.raw_decode(x)
({'tags': '{Artist}{Singer}', 'name': 'Bob Dylan'}, 47)
>>> x=x[47:]
>>> d.raw_decode(x)
({'name': 'Michael Jackson'}, 27)
```

raw_decode returns a 2-tuple, the first element being the decoded JSON and the second being the offset in the string of the next byte after the JSON ended.

To loop until the end or until an invalid JSON element is encountered:

```
>>> while True:
...   try:
...     j,n = d.raw_decode(x)
...   except ValueError:
...     break
...   print(j)
...   x=x[n:]
... 
{'name': 'Bob Dylan', 'tags': '{Artist}{Singer}'}
{'name': 'Michael Jackson'}
```

When the loop breaks, inspection of x will reveal if it has processed the whole string or had encountered a JSON syntax error.

With a very long file of short elements you might read a chunk into a buffer and apply the above loop, concatenating anything that's left over with the next chunk after the loop breaks.

Comment: This is an excellent approach and it works really good but is too slow for computing large files.

Comment: An empty string is not valid JSON.  Catch the exception ... am adding to my answer

Comment: You could simple iterate while the strings is not empty

Comment: I ended up by parsing the file with my regex and saving up the places where it was broken. Then with your answer I was able to join those parts of string and parse again the json.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `jq` command line utility to transfer your input to json. Let's say you have the following input:

*input.txt:*

```
{"name":"Bob Dylan", "tags":"{Artist}{Singer}"}{"name": "Michael Jackson"}
```

You can use `jq -s`, which consumes multiple json documents from input and transfers them into a single output array:

```
jq -s . input.txt
```

Gives you:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Bob Dylan",
    "tags": "{Artist}{Singer}"
  },
  {
    "name": "Michael Jackson"
  }
]
```

I've just realized that there are python bindings for `libjq`. Meaning you 
don't need to use the command line, you can use `jq` directly in python.

https://github.com/mwilliamson/jq.py

However, I've not tried it so far. Let me give it a try :) ...

Update: The above library is nice, but it does not support the slurp mode so far.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make a parser ... I dont think regex can help you for

```
data = ""
curlies = []
def get_dicts(file_text):
    for letter in file_text:
        data += letter
        if letter == "{":
           curlies.append(letter)
        elif letter == "}":
           curlies.pop() # remove last
           if not curlies:
              yield json.loads(data)
              data = ""
```

note that this does not actually solve the problem that `{name:"bob"}` is not valid json ... `{"name":"bob"}` is

this will also break in the event you have weird unbalanced parenthesis inside of strings ie `{"name":"{{}}}"}` would break this

really your json is so broken based on your example your best bet is probably to edit it by hand and fix the code that is generating it ... if that is not feasible you may need to write a more complex parser using pylex or some other grammar library (effectively writing your own language parser)

Comment: But what if there's a "}" inside a string? You can't just say "we'll also count quote marks and ignore curlies when the quote count isn't zero" because what if there's an escaped quote mark inside the string? You can't just say "we won't count a quote mark towards the quote count if the previous character is a backslash" because what if there's an escaped backslash inside a string followed by the actual quote mark that terminates that string?

Comment: fair point ... as long as the curlies in the string are balanced though this should still work (if its just random curlies it will certainly break ...)

Comment: Just use raw_decode method of json.JSONDecoder. See my answer.