# multiple json dictionaries python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file with multiple json dictionaries:
the format is as following

```
{"x":"1", "y":"2", "z": "3"}{"x": "2","y":"3", "z":"4"}{"x":"3", "y":"4", "z":"5"}
```

How can I convert this to one json dictionary format as following:

```
{"items":[{"x":"1", "y":"2", "z": "3"},{"x": "2","y":"3", "z":"4"},{"x":"3", "y":"4", "z":"5"}]}
```

Comment: That file is broken. Return it to sender with kind regards to provide valid JSON, or at least a sane format.

Comment: Unfortunately I have generated this file myself from a python script which gets this data from a website.

Comment: It's very, very common to find multiple JSON elements concatenated in one file. People do not read the JSON specification or the Python json module doc. quote:  "Unlike pickle and marshal, JSON is not a framed protocol so trying to serialize more objects with repeated calls to dump() and the same fp will result in an invalid JSON file. "

Answer (score 2):

Already mostly answered here: [Importing wrongly concatenated JSONs in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019907/importing-wrongly-concatenated-jsons-in-python/36021001#36021001)

That shows you how to pick up each JSON element from a concatenated list of them (which is not valid JSON) using `json.JSONDecoder` method `raw_decode()`. The rest is a simple matter of concatenating strings `'{"items":['`, `element1`, `","`, `element2`, ... `"]"` or alternatively, accumulating them as a list, wrapping that with a one-item dict and if required, dumping that json as a string with `json.dumps`

OK expanding on that

```
import json
d = json.JSONDecoder()

# get your concatenated json into x, for example maybe
x = open('myfile.json','r').read()

jlist=[]
while True:
   try:
      j,n = d.raw_decode(x) 
      jlist.append(j)
   except ValueError: 
      break
   x=x[n:]

# my original thought was
result = '{"items":[' + 
     ','.join( [ str(s) for s in jlist] ) +
     ']'

# but this is neater
result = json.dumps( { "items":jlist })

# and of course if you want it for programmatic use, just
result_as_json = dict( items=jlist )
```

Comment: I visited the link, but it doesn't seem to help much. I am a newbie in Python.

Comment: import json

data = []
with open('c:\\users\\fawads\\desktop\\short.json') as f:
    data = f.read()
    d = json.JSONDecoder()
    d.raw_decode(data)
with open('c:\\users\\fawads\\desktop\\data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)

I tried this, but it didnt help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used the above code and things are now in proper shape :)